# How to write %in% equivalent of R in siuba python package?

Tags: python

I am trying **siuba** package in `python` for first time.

**Doubt:** How to filter for multiple elements using `siuba`. I mean how to write **%in%** in siuba python code:

**R equivalent:**

```
df %>% filter(Country %in% c('Germany','France','Spain'))
```

Python siuba attempt

```
country_list = ['Germany','France','Spain']

df >> filter(_.Country %in% country_list )
```

Its a simple thing but my attempts so far didn't work and also couldn't find it on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`siuba` wraps `pandas` operations in its own syntax.

The `pandas` operation to filter values based on a list of values is [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), this works in `siuba` syntax as follows:

```py
country_list = ['Germany', 'France', 'Spain']
df >> filter(_.Country.isin(country_list))
```

Sample Program:

```py
import pandas as pd
from siuba import filter, _

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Germany', 'France', 'Spain', 'Portugal']})

country_list = ['Germany', 'France', 'Spain']
df >> filter(_.Country.isin(country_list))
```

`df`:

```
    Country
0   Germany
1    France
2     Spain
3  Portugal
```

`After filter`:

```
   Country
0  Germany
1   France
2    Spain
```